# PHP/PDO/MySQL if statement in BETWEEN clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, between

I'm trying to return records all records from a store within a certain date range. However, if the store opened after the date, I want to use the open date. Is it possible to do something like this? I'm using PHP with PDO and MySQL:

```
select
   store_name,
   daily_sales
from
   mytable
where
   date between (if(open_date > :start_date, open_date, :start_date) and :end_date
```

Comment: Simple answer: Why don't you try it? It's easy enough to simply hack up a query with some valid values and try running it yourself. It'll probably take you less time to do that than it did to type up and format the question here.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that an `IF()` expression would be invalid where an expression is permitted?

Comment: Would a store have records before its open date?  If not the open date can be ignored and you an just use the start date.

Comment: Some stores have pre-opening parties that we store but don't want to includes for this report.

Comment: The `IF` can be simplified to `GREATEST(:start_date, open_date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do it like this:

```
select
   store_name,
   daily_sales
from
   mytable
where
   date between (select if(open_date > :start_date, open_date, :start_date)) and :end_date
```

Answer (score -1):

**Q:** Is it possible to do something like this?

**A:** Yes.

Of course, you'll want to remove the extraneous paren from in front of `if`. There's no closing paren, and even if there were, wrapping that expression in parens is unnecessary in that context.

There's one potential problem to note.  The PDO documentation isn't explicit about this, but I don't think you can use a named bind placeholder more than once in the statement. For the example statement, you'd need to use three *different* names for the placeholders, for example

```
date BETWEEN IF(open_date > :start_date, open_date, :start_date_2) AND :end_date
                                                               ^^
```

The code would need to bind values for all three of the named placeholders.

Similar to the pattern if the code used three positional placeholders.

```
date BETWEEN IF(open_date > ? , open_date, ?) AND ?
```